# Closed sets in the Zariski topology on $\mathbb{P}^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $U_1, \ldots, U_{n+1}$ be the affine charts on $\mathbb{P}^n$ and let
$X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ be any subset.

Show that if $X$ is closed in the Zariski topology on $\mathbb{P}^n$ then
$X \cap U_i$ is closed in the Zariski topology on each $U_i \cong \mathbb{A}^n$

I'm unsure what is meant here: does this ask to show that $X \cap U_i$ is closed in the subspace topology (which is clear by definition) or to show that it is closed in $\mathbb{A}^n$?
If the latter, how would one think about this intersection?

Comment: Can you say more about why one is easy but the other is hard for you? After all, $U_i\cong\Bbb A^n$ as varieties/schemes/etc, so in particular they're homeomorphic...

Comment: What is your definition of the Zariski topology on $\mathbb{P}^n$?

Comment: If $X$ is given by vanishing of homogeneous polynonials $F_i(x_1, \ldots, x_{n+1})$, then the same polynomials define the affine cone over $X$, which is a subset of $\mathbb A^{n+1}$. Then you take its intersection with hyperplane $x_i=1$, and it is Zariski closed as a subset of this hyperplane, which means that $X\cap U_i$ is closed in $U_i$.